# Drop down menu won't appear. Am I incorrectly using a selector?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a drop down menu (class is "scenemenu") that appears when I hover over the li class "scenebutton". However, I'm not sure of the CSS selector I'm using is correct. Can somebody help me fix it please? Here is my code.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    background-color:#000;
    background-image:url(Pictures/Plundergem-Title.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 0%;
    height:1500px;
}
.menu-list{
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#E92A27;
    font-family:"Mayan Font";
    font-size:36px;
}
.menu-list li{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.menu-list li:hover{
    background-color:#E92A27;
    color:#000;
}

@font-face{
    src:url(CFCivilisationMaya-Regular.ttf);
    font-family:"Mayan Font";

}
.menu-block{
    width:200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:200px;
    left:-23px;
    border-right:3px solid #E92A27;
}
#menu-seperation{
    width:150px;
    position:fixed;
    left:20px;
    top:270px;

}


#flash-container{
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    width:700px;
    left:300px;
    top:700px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"Cataneo BT";
    font-size:18px;
}

#flash-container p{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"Text Font";

}

@font-face{
    font-family:"Text Font";
    src:url(TT0952M_.TTF);

}


.scenemenu{

    list-style-type:none;
    color:#E92A27;
    font-family:"Mayan Font";
    position:fixed;
    top:297px;
    left:190px;
    z-index:2000;
    width:150px;
    display:none;    }

.scenemenu li{
    position:relative;
    left:-50px;
}

li.scenebutton:hover ul.scenemenu{
    display:inline;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-scrollto.js"></script>
    <script src="animation.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Pictures/Gem Icon.png" />
    <title>Plundergem Adventure Game</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="menu-block">
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li>HOME</li>
        <hr id="menu-seperation"/>
        <br style="line-height: .3em" />

        <li id="scenebutton">SCENES</li>
        <ul class="scenemenu">
            <li>SCENE 2</li>
            <li>SCENE 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="flash-container">
    <img src="Pictures/Scene_1_converted.jpg" width="700" height="504" />
    <p>​The sky is dark, the grass is dark, and even the dark is quite dark. This will do a perfect job of setting the mood. Unfortunately, it is raining, meaning that you will be unable to pull off your uncanny Batman impressions. Will you climb the temple stairs, or will you head home?​</p>
    <br />
    <a href="Enter the Temple 2nd Scene/index.php"><u>1. Climb the temple stairs in an over manly fashion.</u></a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a><u>2. Run away and never come back.</u></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got stuff outside an `<li>` element but inside an `<ul>` element. Surely this does not validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tthe `ul` you are trying to select comes after the `li`; you should move the `ul` you are trying to display within the `li` instead of after it.

```
<li id="scenebutton">
    SCENES
    <ul class="scenemenu">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Also, you need to use the id selector for `scenebutton`.

```
#scenebutton:hover ul.scenemenu {
```